# Orchard CMS Projection: filter based on blog name/id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

Let's say I have multiple blogs on my Orchard site. How do I create a projection that shows posts only from the blog that I specify e.g. either by its name or id?

I think it can be done using a custom filter but there seem to be no doc/howto out there.

Please let me know where I should put the code too, I've been programming for ages but am very new to Orchard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the IFilterProvider interface, you can see how to do it here: 
http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5